# Ember JS Change the color and title of a button component when a date is picked from date-picker

Tags: ember.js, web-applications

I have a web app in which there are two components - date picker and button.

When I select a date from date-picker, the button's title and color should change.

This is my hbs code where two components are given:

```
{{bootstrap-datepicker value=expiresAt todayHighlight=true todayBtn=true startDate=startDate changeDate="changeDateAction" autoclose=true}}
{{button-custom title="Previous Date" startDate=startDate status=1 id="button1"}}
```

The button-custom is created by me.

When I select a date, the function in datepicker named changeDateAction() will be called. I have a function in button component's controller, named changeValues() which when called will do my task.

How can I call changeValues() (which is in button-custom.js) from changeDateAction() which is in another file?

Please be as simple as possible as I'm beginner in Ember JS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd like to inform a component (`button-custom`) about a change in a sibling component (`bootstrap-datepicker`). You've already set up an action handler (`changeDateAction`) that informs the parent component/controller about the change. In order to propagate that change to `button-custom`, I'd suggest to just pass the *effect* you'd like to achieve down to it:

```
{{bootstrap-datepicker changeDate="changeDateAction" (...)}}
{{button-custom title=title color=color (...)}}
```

Like this, you can control the appearance of the button from the outside by modifying `title` and `color`. Like that, the logic is moved to the parent component/controller, and the button component becomes a "dumb" presentational component.

The basic concept behind this is called "Data down, Actions up" (DDAU), and i'd highly recommend to read up on it (for example [here](https://emberigniter.com/send-closure-actions-up-data-owner/) if you're learning Ember!